# Slow down case fan on MSI P43-C51 motherboard?

Tags: fan, case, speedfan

Bought a case fan that specifically says, "sensors to allow speed control", rated at 3000RPM.

Installed Speedfan, messed around with settings, no dice.  Same goes for the MSI OverClock Center software which allows you to change the fans as well.

Have no problem with CPU fan, just can't control SYSFAN1 (haven't tried SYSFAN2), even though it sounds like the motherboard supports it.

In the BIOS, there's a few fan-related features and turning them off and on, changing settings, etc. has no effect.

Is there a fan I can buy that has a built-in speed controller on it?  It's a freakin' Hoover right now -- blowing full blast at 3100~ RPM even though the temps are all under 40C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how is the fan connected up? it is connected to the motherboard, rather than to the power supply directly, right?

I don't know of any fans with built-in control, but you can buy standalone fan speed controllers for not too much (or for a lot of money, if you want high-end features).

manual fan controllers:

1. http://xoxide.com/fanmate.html
2. http://xoxide.com/sunbeam-pci-fan-controller.html

automatic fan controller:

1. http://xoxide.com/logisys-digital-fan-controller-3-5-silver.html
2. http://xoxide.com/lian-li-tr-03-thermal-monitor-fan-control-blk.html

Comment: Fan's connected to the mobo; standard 3-pin.